# How to delete row in database in MySQL using JSP?

Tags: mysql, jsp

This is my function. It gets two parameter id of the product and a name. the function delete with MySQL command a row in a database. I know the that there are missing lines in my code, I'm stuck and I don't know how to finish it. I also know that my SQL line is not correct. I'm not sure if combined the String "name" right.

```java
public static deletePro(int cat, String name) {

    DB db = new DB();
    String sql = "delete from products where pname=+'name' and catid=" + cat;
    ResultSet rs = db.getResultSet(sql);

    try {
        while (rs.next()) {
            Products prod = new Products();
            prod.setNamePro(rs.getString(name));
            prod.setAmount(rs.getInt(cat));
        }

        rs.close();
        db.closeCon();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i want to use this "sql" line to delete from database.> My question is if my code is right?

Comment: "*My question is if my code is right?*" Ha ha. That leads to only one question which is, why not try it on your own to see if it is right? The said SQL statement appears to be wonky and not compilable. Formulate and try an SQL statement directly on the back-end database (MySQL terminal, MySQL WorkBench, MySQL GUI or whatever) and embed it in the Java code if and only if it fully succeeds on the back-end database. Moreover, always insist upon using a [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html). This way SQL injection chances will be mitigated.

Answer (score 2):

> String sql = "delete from products where pname=+'name' and catid=" + cat;

This should be:

```
String sql = "DELETE FROM products WHERE pname='" + name + "' and catid = " + cat;
```

And the preferred way is to use [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html), which would alleviate the pain of string manipulation in your query by using placeholders:

```
String sql = "DELETE FROM products WHERE pname= ? and catid = ?";

PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1, name);
ps.setInt(2, cat);

ps.executeUpdate();
```

Hope this helps.